# Using SimpleListItemActivated1 with custom Adapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have built a custom Adapter for my Android app in Xamarin, because I wanted to customize the ListviewItems and it works.
The problem is that I wanted the selected Listitem to be highlighted. So I want to use the `SimpleListItemActivated1` flag. But you can use this flag with the `ArrayAdapter` in this context:

```
_list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1,
                        tempNames);
```

But I have implemented my own Adapter and I need it to customize my listview items:

```
_adapter = new AndroidUI.KundenViewAdapter (this,_kunden);
_list.Adapter = _adapter
```

How can use the `SimpleListItemActivated1` in my Adapter?

The code for my Adapter is the following:

```
namespace AndroidUI
{
public class KundenViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<BusinessLayer.Kunde>
{
    private readonly Activity _context;
    private List<Kunde> _kunden;

    public KundenViewAdapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<Kunde> kunden)
    {
        _kunden = kunden.ToList ();
        _context = context;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return  _kunden.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64 ( _kunden[position].ID);
    }

    public override Kunde this[int position]
    {
        get { return _kunden[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PersonListItem, null);


        Kunde kunde = _kunden[position];
        TextView textview = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.nameTextView);

        textview.Text = kunde.Name;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (kunde.Nummer))
            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.NummerTextView).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        else
            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.NummerTextView).Text = kunde.Nummer;

        return view;
    }
}

public class LieferantViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<BusinessLayer.Lieferant>
{
    private readonly Activity _context;
    private List<Lieferant> _lieferant;

    public LieferantViewAdapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<Lieferant> lieferant)
    {
        _lieferant = lieferant.ToList ();
        _context = context;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return  _lieferant.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64 ( _lieferant[position].ID);
    }

    public override Lieferant this[int position]
    {
        get { return _lieferant[position]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PersonListItem, null);

        Lieferant lieferant = _lieferant[position];
        TextView textview = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.nameTextView);

        textview.Text = lieferant.Name;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty (lieferant.Nummer))
            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.NummerTextView).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        else
            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.NummerTextView).Text = lieferant.Nummer;

        return view;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare `View selectedRow;` in a class and  Add below code in `setonitemclickListner`

```
if (selectedRow != null) {
            selectedRow.setBackgroundResource(color.transparent);
        }
        selectedRow = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background);
```

This will work fine version 3.0 and above

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just had to change a little for Xamarin.Android, but it worked completely.

Comment: This is incorrect as it will highlight every row that is clicked. also it will mess the view recycling. **on it's own this code is not enough to achieve correct behaviour, it should be edited**

Comment: @Alex.F did you tried my answer, try once and let me know it will not highlight every row. as i said it works fine on above 3.0 version of android.